# How does package.el handle changes in macros when updating?

Tags: elisp, package

Let's assume there is a package `P` containing two files,

```
  P/base.el
  P/utils.el
```

, where the `base.el` file requires `utils.el` at runtime and `utils.el` contains a macro `M`. Upon first installation of `P`, package.el downloads, extracts and compiles it.

Now assume the package maintainer updated `P` to `P'` and in the process modified `M` to `M'`.  The package user now attempts to update his package via package-list. Since `P` is a useful package, it is also loaded.  Again package.el downloads and extracts `P'`.  But I don't see how the code from the updated macro `M'` gets into the compiled file `P'/base.el`, since the feature `utils.el` is already provided, so, I assume, and the compiler is happy to use the old definition `M`.

The question I have about this is simply whether this is a correct analysis ?

Comment: Not hundred percent sure, but there's a good chance that `(require 'package)` will actually re-load and re-evaluate the package if the file is newer. So the macro definition is likely to be updated. However, the places where expansion already happened will not be updated.

Comment: FYI, it doesn't look to me as if `require` (at least as at 24.4.1) performs any such check. If the feature was registered as having been loaded, I believe that's all that matters.

Comment: Obviously, explicitly `load`ing the recompiled library would resolve the issue, and it's certainly possible that the package manager does exactly that after updating libraries which were previously loaded.

Comment: @phils It doesn't do that on 24.4, but does in 25.1. Explicitly loading the file in your package is indeed a workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I don't see how the code from the updated macro M' gets into the compiled file P'/base.el, since the feature utils.el is already provided, [...]

It doesn't. Or, actually, it **didn't**.

### The bug

Your analysis is correct. 
It was [a bug](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2014-10/msg00567.html) in `package.el`, and it's [been fixed](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-diffs/2014-12/msg00254.html) on [this commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=c13baa10d55ec863d3ceaea48c6b2959ece98198) for the next Emacs release. As of
the next version, when `package.el` upgrades a package that has been
loaded in this session, it will reload a package after installing it.

### The workaround

One workaround is to `load` a package instead of `require`ing it.
Though this is bad style, I would consider it an acceptable
compromise, if you *know* you'll be affected by this.
You know you'll be affected by this if your package is about to make
use of a newly released feature of a pre-existing macro that's on another file (or another package).

Comment: [This](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=c13baa10d55ec863d3ceaea48c6b2959ece98198)
looks like the relevant commit.

Comment: Though, I think it's still broken, since the reloading happens *after*
the package was compiled (with the old macros).

Comment: @politza oh yes. I misinterpreted the question (I'll update the answer later) . This was fixed for macros from another package. It still needs work for macros inside the same package that are on a different file. Fortunately, the `load` instead of `require` workaround still works for that situation, and it's kind of a no brainer there.

Comment: And it's still listed as [bug
#10125](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=10125). I should
have checked there first, but the assumed implication of hundreds of
broken packages out there kept me from doing so...